# Is there a way to cancel a transaction without having to pay a gas fee?

Tags: gas, gas-price, fees

Is there a way a cancel a stuck transaction without having a pay a gay fee?

Or does any successful transaction, except the ones sent from the same account with the same nonce, requires paying gas fees?

Answer (score 2):

No.
When you signed it, anyone (from the miners) can take it and process. With putting your signature you have made your authorization to execute the transaction. In general you have to raise gas price (10% or 15%) on transaction with the same nonce to resubmit.

Comment: does cancelling a TX always incurr a gas fee?

Comment: yes, you always have to pay a gas fee, often higher than the original tx that you want to cancel (as it needs to replace it). https://info.etherscan.com/how-to-cancel-ethereum-pending-transactions/